# BATCH Preventing users from opening file from outside the program?

Tags: windows, batch-file, plugins

I have a plugin system on a program written in batch, as follows; (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill)

```
:plugindragon
echo.
echo Plugins
echo ==============
dir /b plugins\*.cmd
echo.
echo Enter the name of the plugin you want to run.
set /p plugin=root/plugins/plugin_dragon.jr@Root:~$ 
start "" plugins\%plugin%
goto root
```

Is there any way to prevent users of my program from opening said plugins without running the pluginDragon script? As in they can't just directly go into the plugins folder and double click the applications (as they're all written in batch). They'd need to use the "terminal" window to open them, and only that.

Comment: Make them hidden files?

Comment: Also set permissions that forbid execution and temporarily clear those via `icacls` in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of your script that does the following:

- Makes the files hidden and system files using `attrib`
- Changes the permissions on the files to make them unopenable using `icacls`

  ```
  :plugindragon
  echo.
  echo Plugins
  echo ==============
  dir /b plugins\*.cmd
  echo.
  echo Enter the name of the plugin you want to run (Exclude extension).
  set /p plugin=root/plugins/plugin_dragon.jr@Root:~$ 

  :: Grant permission to access file
      icacls "plugins\%plugin%.cmd" /grant everyone:F /T /C /Q>nul 2>&1

  :: Unhide the file
      attrib -h -s -r -a "plugins\%plugin%.cmd" >nul

  start /wait "" plugins\%plugin%.cmd

  :: Hide the file
  attrib +h +s +r +a "plugins\%plugin%.cmd" >nul

  :: Denies access to the file
  icacls "plugins\%plugin%.cmd" /deny everyone:F /T /C /Q>nul 2>&1

  goto root
  ```